# How do I make a comparison between the objects in a vector and an int? : Java

Tags: java, vector, comparison

I am trying to use an if condition to compare the objects in a vector, which represent integers, with values of type int, so that I can increment those which appear in the vector according to how many times they appear in the vector. I can't for the life of me get it to compile. Here is the code.

```
package countjava;
import java.util.*;

public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector vect = new Vector();
        int[] amounts = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++) {
            VectorIntObject intObject = 
                    new VectorIntObject((int)Math.random() * 100);
            vect.add(intObject);
        }

        Collections.sort(vect);
        for (int i =0; 1 < 40; i++) {
            System.out.println(vect.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++) {
                Object ourObject = vect.get(i);
                if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
                    amounts[j]++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++) {
                System.out.println(amounts[j]);
        }
    }
}

class VectorIntObject {
    int value;
    public VectorIntObject(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getVectorIntValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

The comparison should happen in the nested for loops about half way down. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The compiler is an awesome instrument.  One of its greatest features is reporting the error in English.  Please reciprocate.

Comment: Is that your real code? Your sorting should fail since your VectorIntObject isn't comparable, and you haven't invoked sort with a custom comparator.

Comment: BTW: Vector is a legacy class which was replace in Java 1.2 (1998) by ArrayList. I wouldn't use it unless you have to.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I don't think in Tertiary level they emphasise that. List and Vectors are still taught but nobody mentions of deprecation of Vector in java.

Comment: @The Elite, Which is why I thought I might mention it.  It was probably a legacy class when the teacher learnt Java. :)

Comment: Good to know about the deprecation, too. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this will not compile:

```
Object ourObject = vect.get(i);
if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
    amounts[j]++;
}
```

As you're returning an `Object` from a vector and trying to call `getVectorIntValue()` without typecasting it to `VectorIntObject`.

If you're using JDK 5 and higher, I suggest using Generics, and assign a type to Vector

```
Vector<VectorIntObject> vect = new Vector<VectorIntObject>();
```

Then this will be valid:

```
VectorIntObject ourObject = vect.get(i);
if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
    amounts[j]++;
}
```

Otherwise, *typecasting* will do

```
VectorIntObject ourObject = (VectorIntObject)vect.get(i);
if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
    amounts[j]++;
}
```

Comment: Typecasting was my original solution, but it makes the compiler claim "unreachable statement" for the for loop directly above it, and I can't figure out why. I made a mistake posting it without the typecast.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The "unreachable" statement problem is because of this

```
for (int i =0; 1 < 40; i++)
```

1 is always less than 40, so this is an infinite loop. You meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
```

---

The problem is that your `ourObject` variable is of type `Object`, so you can't call `getVectorIntValue` on it - that's not a method declared in `Object`.

You should be using the collection in a *generic* way. That way the compiler will "know" that the collection contains `VectorIntObject` references.

```
Vector<VectorIntObject> vect = new Vector<VectorIntObject>();

// Code as before...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++) {
        // Note type of ourObject here, with no need to cast
        VectorIntObject ourObject = vect.get(i);
        if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
            amounts[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Separately, I'd recommend using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

If for some reason you *can't* use Java 1.5 or higher, so can't use generics, you have to cast in your loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++) {
        VectorIntObject ourObject = (VectorIntObject) vect.get(i);
        if (ourObject.getVectorIntValue() == j) {
            amounts[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

This basically has the same effect at execution-time as the generic version, but the compiler isn't able to give you as much help because it doesn't know what kind of value will be in the collection.

Comment: Yes, ok, I had it casted this way and should have posted it like that, but when I do, a secondary problem arises. The first line of the above for loop gets a compiler error "unreachable statement". I took the cast off to see if it would fix the "unreachable", which it did, but with the problems you pointed out above.

Comment: @MassStrike: See my edit (at the top of the answer). *This is why you should always quote any compiler errors when you ask a question.*